# What is the grade of the following hadith that talks about a future event?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

> حدثنا عبد الله بن مروان عن الهيثم بن عبد الرحمن عمن حدثه عن علي بن أبي
>   طالب رضى الله عنه قال يخرج رجل قبل المهدي من أهل بيته بالمشرق يحمل
>   السيف على عاتقه ثمانية أشهر يقتل ويمثل ويتوجه إلى بيت المقدس فلا يبلغه
>   حتى يموت
>
> Al-Haytham bin Abd-Al-Rahman narrated based someone that Ali bin Abi
>   Taleb (r.a.), who is the cousin, son-in-law, and the 4th successor
>   (Caliph) of Prophet Mohammad صلى الله عليه وسلم said: "A man will
>   come out from the East before the Mahdi, from his Household (family),
>   carrying a sword for 8 months, killing and maiming people. He heads
>   toward Jerusalem and dies once he reaches (conquers) it."  (Nuaim Ibn
>   Hammad's Kitab Al-Fitan)

Is it a sahih hadith?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 'Abdullah ibn Marwan' narrated us from 'Al-Haitham ibn Abd Al-Rehman' from
>   '**Someone**' who narrated it from 'Ali ibn Abi Talib'

This particular chain of narration is broken; one narrator is unknown (*majhool* ). We do not know who heard it from Ali (r.a). Therefore, it does not fulfill a basic criterion of being a sahih hadith.

Comment: A more correct translation of the statement is:"... from a person whom narrated (him) from 'Ali ibn abi Talib".